# Angular2 and TweenMax - Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object

Tags: angular, scroll, gsap

I have some problem. I want to create the button, that scroll whole page to top.
Here is my code.

**app.component.html**

```
<p>lorem...</p> <!-- 100 times -->
<div (click)="scroll()">Scroll to top</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { TabHeaderComponent } from './components/tab/tab-header/tab-header.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TweenLite } from 'gsap';
import ScrollToPlugin from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}


  public scroll() {
    TweenLite.to(window, 1, {
          scrollTo: 0
    });
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{


"name": "tabs-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/gsap": "^1.19.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

And if I click on the button i see really huge ammount of errors

> Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object

Do you know, what's wrong? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I already found the solution! It is really eraly simple. Just change `window` to `document.body`. Here is an example.

**scroll() function**

```
public scroll() {
    // can you tell me why 'document.body.scrollTop' is always equals to 0
    // in Chrome ???
    if(document.body.scrollTop !== 0) {
        TweenLite.to(document.body, 1, {scrollTop: 0});
    }
    else {
        TweenLite.to(document.documentElement, 1, {scrollTop: 0});
    }
}
```

I hope it helps